# How to extract values from Some() in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have Some() type Map[String, String], such as

```
Array[Option[Any]] = Array(Some(Map(String, String)
```

I want to return it as

```
Array(Map(String, String))
```

I've tried few different ways of extracting it-
Let's say if

```
val x = Array(Some(Map(String, String)
val x1 = for (i <- 0 until x.length) yield { x.apply(i) }
```

but this returns IndexedSeq(Some(Map)), which is not what I want.

I tried pattern matching,

```
x.foreach { i =>
  i match {
    case Some(value) => value
    case _ => println("nothing") }}
```

another thing I tried that was somewhat successful was that

```
x.apply(0).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
```

will do something what I want, but it only gets 0th index of the entire array and I'd want all the maps in the array.
How can I extract Map type out of Some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the pattern is either to use transformations on the `Option[T]`, like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.

The problem is, we'll need to add a type cast to retrieve the underlying `Map[String, String]` from `Any`. So we'll use `flatten` to remove any potentially `None` types and unwrap the `Option`, and `asInstanceOf` to retreive the type:

```
scala> val y = Array(Some(Map("1" -> "1")), Some(Map("2" -> "2")), None)
y: Array[Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]] = Array(Some(Map(1 -> 1)), Some(Map(2 -> 2)), None)

scala> y.flatten.map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])
res7: Array[Map[String,String]] = Array(Map(1 -> 1), Map(2 -> 2))
```

Comment: I think the trouble is that I want to get rid of the Any type to operate on Map[String, String] but the getOrElse still returns Array[Any].

Comment: @user3551523 You're working with an `Array[Any]`, or an `Array[Option[Map[String, String]]]`?

Comment: @user3551523 I see. Do you know that all the objects in the underlying `Array` will necessarily be a `Map[String, String]`?

Comment: Yeah they're all Map[String, String] but it's encapsulated within Some. So what I have right now is Some(Map[String, String]).

Comment: your edited version is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want an `Array[Any]` from your `Array[Option[Any]]`, you can use this for expression:

```
for {
    opt <- x
    value <- opt
} yield value
```

This will put the values of all the non-empty `Option`s inside a new array.

It is equivalent to this:

```
x.flatMap(_.toArray[Any])
```

Here, all options will be converted to an array of either 0 or 1 element. All these arrays will then be flattened back to one single array containing all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Also when you talk just about single value you can try `Some("test").head` and for null simply `Some(null).flatten`

Comment: `Some("test").head` returns type `String` whereas `Some(null).flatten` returns type `Option[Nothing]`. I don't see how they are related.